# Can't get Libraries Maven Dependencies to show up

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I switched from Juno Eclipse to Kepler and imported my Maven project. However "Maven Dependencies" doesn't show up under Project-Properties-Java Build Path-Libraries and thus i can't compile my project. In Maven Repositories view i can see all my dependencies jar files under Local Repositories. I can manually add External Jar Files but there must be a right way to load them dynamically. I can run "maven install" successfully from Eclipse. I've tried all suggestions from this forum such as - run Maven-Update Project, unchecked Maven-Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects, Window-Preferences-check "Download repository index updates on startup" and "Update Maven projects on startup". Something is weird about Kepler Eclipse. What am i missing?

Here is my pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>actives</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.XXX</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>  
                </descriptors>

                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> <!--  Include all depedencies in build -->
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!--<appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>

    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>


</build>

<properties>
    <root>.</root>
    <xxx.releases>http://xxx.xxx.local/mave</xxx.releases>
    <xxxx.releases>http://xxx.xxx.local/xxx/releases</xxx.releases>
    <xxx.snapshots>http://xxx.associatesys.local/xxx/snapshots</xxx.snapshots>
    <xxx.releases.distribution>scp://xxx.associatesys.local/../../../srv/www/release/xxxx/releases</xxx.releases.distribution>
    <xxx.snapshots.distribution>scp://xxx.xxx.local/../../../srv/www/release/xxx/snapshots</xxx.snapshots.distribution>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>central</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>       


    <repository>
        <id>xxx-central</id>
        <name>XXXCentral</name>
        <url>http://xxx.xxx.local/maven2/central</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>xxx-releases</id>
        <name>Internal ReleasesRepository</name>
        <url>${xxx.releases}</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>xxx-releases</id>
        <name>XXXReleases Repository</name>
        <url>${xxx.releases}</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>xxx-snapshots</id>
        <name>XXXX Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>${xxx.snapshots}</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>interval:30</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>sqljdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-xxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-xxx</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>xxx-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>xxx-releases</id>
        <name>XXXXReleases Repository</name>
        <url>${xxx.releases.distribution}</url>
    </repository>

    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>xxx-snapshots</id>
        <name>XXXSnapshots Repository</name>
        <url>${xxx.snapshots.distribution}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

UPDATE: i solved this problem by copy and paste .classpath and .project files from another Maven project in Eclipse (Kepler) that was created with no issues. I made minor adjustments to these 2 files. I compared pom.xml files and found no discrepancies that would prevent Eclipse from creating my Maven project. It's not an ideal solution but it works for now, no time to solving Eclipse "mysteries". Thanks for the below comments, they pointed me into a right direction and helped to understand a problem better.

Comment: Did you use the Import->Existing Maven project in a fresh workspace?

Comment: m2e respects current Eclipse meta files.  If you cannot create a fresh checkout from your versioning control system without Eclipse meta files, you should manually remove .settings, .project and .classsomething from your current project before attemtpting to import it again.

Comment: Thanks. I removed my project and removed .settings,.project,.classpath and Imported a project again. It looks different, missing small 'J' on the projects' name icon. It looks more like a library then a dev project. For versioning control i use Clear Case. I have this projected checked out and just want to add to Eclipse for further development. I didn't want to do "Create Maven project" because i already have pom.xml with all dependencies listed.

Comment: Then your pom.xml is broken.

Comment: Possible. I just started using maven, no experience. Although i can build my project with this pom.xml. I added my pom.xml content above. Please give me ideas on what to modify there.

Comment: Well if it works on the command prompt then the pom is not broken, easy as that. It is the most common reason I have experienced for the dependencies to not show up though. Just to be sure, when you open up the pom.xml file in Eclipse, in what editor does it open it? As a Maven pom file, or as a regular XML file? If it is a maven pom file, is there an error indicator at the top of the file? Does the Eclipse errors view show any error at all?

Comment: My pom.xml opens up as Maven pom file with tabs at the bottom. No errors specified in that editor. Error log view shows PLug-in related errors (m2e). I've tried to Import another maven project and it created normally with Maven Dependencies showing up. So, probably something "funny" with my pom.xml

Comment: Consider opening a new question about your Pom.xml.